# Embedding a MFMessageComposer in a custom Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm using LGSemiModalNavController for the majority of my modal view controllers within my app.
I want to display the Message Composer in this view controller as well. 
It basically means that the message composer will only pop half way up.

Is this possible? I've tried embedding message composers and image pickers (basically any of the in build view controllers) in the SemiModalNavControllers and it just isn't working. I keep getting the error 'Cannot push a nav controller" (when it is working for other view controllers embedded in the same way).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using `pushViewController:animated:` or `presentViewController:animated:completion `?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

I found out why this was not working for me. Basically, Message Composers are not allowed to be embedded in Navigation Controllers, as a general rule of thumb. 
The Cocoapod I was using is a glorified Nav Controller, so this was where the problem lay.

Big thanks to the makers of LGSemiModalNavControllers who were very helpful and checked my code to clarify the issue.